# Sending form, only hash to url adress Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have problem with sending data from form to database. My forms are generated but they did'nt send any data only redirect after click to send form to url # 
What could by the problem 
Please see it i don't have idea and it's very important project.
https://github.com/szopenkrk/mgr

This is parf from controller:

```
   /**
* @Route("/autor.html", name="url_autor")
* @Template()
*/
    public function autorAction()
    {
        $document = new Work();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
            ->add('contentWork', 'text')
            ->add('workDate', 'date')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('file')
            ->getForm()
        ;

        $loggedUser = $this->getUser();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($this->getRequest());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                /** @var $document \My\WorkBundle\Entity\Work */
                $document->setAuthor($loggedUser);
                $em->persist($document);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("url_thanks"));
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
```

This is part from Entity:
https://github.com/szopenkrk/mgr/blob/master/src/My/WorkBundle/Entity/Work.php

Comment: could you point in your project exatcly places where the problem occurs?

Comment: All places where I send form give me redirect to main root url and #. I think that could be DefaultController of MyWorkBundle

Comment: That's weid becouse form it's normaly rendered in all sites but all the time redirect after send to # and dont send content

Comment: Ok I checked controller it's not a Controller. Something different. What could by part to manage data from form to save it in database ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you render your forms you don't set appropriate action for the form. Instead you put "#" and that's why you got it.

So all you need is change action attribute in your form elements. For exampe in author view change:

```
<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

into

```
<form action="{{ path('url_author') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

Comment: I change that but it's still not working, If form send good data to database, I should get answer from site and redirect site to thanks.html but it's not working probably it's different problem.

Comment: So, what is happening after you send form? If you want any answer you should be more clear in describing problem :)

Comment: Ok when I was sending form I normaly get answer from form thanks.html.twig but from some time i have problem to normaly send form, and still get # nothing else.

Comment: The thing is that controller and Entity was checked and all of forms not work. What could be the problem if form and entity are ok ??

Comment: did you change action="#" into action="{{ path('appropraite_path') }}" in your thanks.html.twig?

Comment: Yes Cyprian I heve something like this:                         <form action="{{ path('url_author') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <input type="submit" value="Zapisz dokument" />
    </form>

Comment: <form  method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
            {{ form_widget(form) }}

            <input type="submit" />
        </form> that it's working. I delate  action="#" and it's working.

Comment: The answer for my problem was to delete from <form part action="#" and it's work well. Topic to close thanks for try help.